# How do you add jQuery datepicker to a text field in a tooltipster tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, tooltipster

I have a jQuery dialogue box that displays a table and for the first header I have a Tooltipster that displays a dateStart and dateEnd input in order to apply a filter to the table. I want to use the jQuery datepicker within these inputs to select the date range however the datepicker doesnt show inside tooltipster. Can this be done?

Tooltip:

```
$jq('.dateFilters').tooltipster({
content: $("table" StartDate  "input class='datepicker' type='text' name='dateFilterStart' " +
            EndDate "input class='datepicker' type='text' name='dateFilterEnd'
});
```

jQuery:

```
$jq(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Comment: probably not if the tooltip plugin doesn't have some sort of callback that fires after it is rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [plugin documentation](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options) suggests you should do this in the `functionReady` option:

```
$jq('.dateFilters').tooltipster({
    content: /* ... your stuff here ... */,
    functionReady: function() { $jq(".datepicker").datepicker(); }
});
```

Disclaimer: I've never used this plugin. This answer is based purely on the documentation provided in the link above.

Comment: Thanks so much! this works, however I had to remove the $jq from the datepicker and keep it as $

Comment: That should be whatever alias the jQuery object has in your application; `$` and `jQuery` are the default but you can set it to anything you like. If the answer helped you out consider ticking it

Comment: Just been testing this in Chrome (we use IE default .... i know) and the datepicker shows up fine but when you click previous or next month the tooltipster disappears before you can set date. Works fine in IE! go figure.